# std::string '+' : cannot add two pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdstring

Why assignment

```
std::string s="aaa"+1
```

works fine while

```
std::string s="aaa"+1+"bbb"
```

gets error `Error   14  error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers`

Comment: You must remember that `"aaa"` is a `const char *`. You can add 1 to a `const char *`, but what would it mean to add two `const char *`'s?

Comment: BTW, that first line isn't an assignment. It's an old-fashioned way to call a constructor.

Comment: `"a" + "bc";` -> g++ complains: *invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'*. Whereas `"a" + 1 + "bc";` g++: *invalid operands of types 'const char\*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'* ("a", the array `const char[]` with a null terminator('\0'), can decay to `const char *` so `"a"+1` is evaluated as `const char*`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `+` operator to concatenate C strings. C strings are just pointers (`const char *`), so if you add a number to it, it will just increment that pointer. Afterwards you convert it to a C++ string:

```
std::string s = "aaa" + 1

                |=======|
                  "aa"
               const char *

           |==============|
                 "aa"
             std::string
```

Then in the second step it fails, when you try to concatenate the second string because while adding a constant to a pointer still made some sense (even though not in your case), there is no way you can make sense of adding two pointers.

```
"aaa" + 1 + "bbb" 

|========|
   "aa"
const char *

            |===|
         const char *
```

To make sure you actually concatenate and don't sum pointers, I'd suggest using a `stringstream`. This also makes sure your constant number is converted properly to a `string`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "aaa" << 1 << "bbb";
std::string s = ss.str();
```

This will work for every type that has the `operator<<` overloaded.

Comment: Just a nitpick: C strings are not really pointers, but `const char[]` that can decay to `const char*`. Not that it really makes a difference here.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string s="aaa"+1;
```

This just compiles, but most likely does not do what you want: It adds 1 to the `const char*` the literal `"aaa"` decays to and then constructs the `std::string` from that pointer, resulting in `s == "aa"`.

When using `operator+` to concatenate strings, at least one of the operands must have type `std::string`, the other one may be `const char*` or something convertible to that. For example:

```
std::string s="aaa"+std::to_string(1);
```

or

```
std::string s="aaa"+std::to_string(1)+"bbb";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first works because `"abc" + 1` is actually the string `"bc"` (changed actual string to make it easier to see). It's simple the same as doing e.g.

```
char array[] = "abc;
std::string str = &array[1];
```

The second doesn't work because you can't append two string literals in that way. You need to make sure one of them already is a `std::string` object.

If you want to create the string `"aaa1"` then I suggest you look at the function [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 0):

This is additional info in this context.
Averagely poor mans solution is to make it half working:

```
void JTube::checkNode(ITCXMLNode current_node, char * tagName){

if(!current_node.d)  {
      string s = "XML tag missing:";
      s = s +  tagName;
      exitreason(s);   
     }
   }
```